# Neo4J Bolt Driver Record contains duplicate entires on COLLECT match

Tags: java, neo4j

My db contains:

- 1 Game (g)
- 2 Expansions (e)
- 2 Categories (c)

When executing the below query in the browser client, I get back exactly what I'd expect. However, using the Java bolt driver, I get odd results.

```
final var query = """
   MATCH (g:Game {name:$name})-[:HAS]->(e:Game),
      (g)-[:HAS]->(c:Category)
   RETURN DISTINCT g, 
      COLLECT(e) AS expansions,
      COLLECT(c) AS categories
""";

try (var session = driver.session()) {
    return session.readTransaction(tx -> {
        final var result = tx.run(query, parameters("name", name));

         final var maybeGame = result.stream().findFirst();
         if (maybeGame.isPresent()) {
             final var gameRecord = maybeGame.get();
             final var gameMap = gameRecord.get("g").asMap();
             final var expansionMaps = gameRecord.get("expansions").asList(MapAccessor::asMap);
             final var categoryMaps = gameRecord.get("categories").asList(MapAccessor::asMap);
             return Optional.of(Game.convert(gameMap, expansionMaps));
        }

        return Optional.empty();

    });
}
```

`gameMap` contains a single game. `expansionsMap` contains 4, duplicating the 2 I'd expect. Same with `categoriesMap`; getting 4, with the 2 I'd expect duplicated.

I can obviously parse that out in my converter, but I don't understand why I'm not getting the correct number of maps. Is there something I can adjust on the query, or the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is not correct.

It works in your Neo4j browser probably in Graph View ( because a visualisation doesn't show the same node twice ), switch to table view or text view to view that your query has 4 results for expansion and categories.

Taking this stub data

```
MERGE (g:Game {id: 1})
MERGE (e1:Game {id: 2})
MERGE (e2:Game {id: 3})
MERGE (c1:Category {id: 4})
MERGE (c2:Category {id: 5})
MERGE (g)-[:HAS]->(e1)
MERGE (g)-[:HAS]->(e2)
MERGE (g)-[:HAS]->(c1)
MERGE (g)-[:HAS]->(c2)
```

```
MATCH (g:Game {id: 1})-[:HAS]->(e:Game),
      (g)-[:HAS]->(c:Category)
   RETURN DISTINCT g, 
      COLLECT(e) AS expansions,
      COLLECT(c) AS categories
```

```
╒════════╤═════════════════════════════════════╤═════════════════════════════════════╕
│"g"     │"expansions"                         │"categories"                         │
╞════════╪═════════════════════════════════════╪═════════════════════════════════════╡
│{"id":1}│[{"id":3},{"id":2},{"id":3},{"id":2}]│[{"id":5},{"id":5},{"id":4},{"id":4}]│
└────────┴─────────────────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────┘
```

---

Modified query making it working

```
MATCH (g:Game {id: 1})-[:HAS]->(e:Game),
      (g)-[:HAS]->(c:Category)
   RETURN g, 
      COLLECT(distinct e) AS expansions,
      COLLECT(distinct c) AS categories
```

```
╒════════╤═══════════════════╤═══════════════════╕
│"g"     │"expansions"       │"categories"       │
╞════════╪═══════════════════╪═══════════════════╡
│{"id":1}│[{"id":3},{"id":2}]│[{"id":5},{"id":4}]│
└────────┴───────────────────┴───────────────────┘
```

Small explanations, there is no need for distinct on `g` since it's a non aggregation function and so will be used as implicit groupBy

https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/aggregating/

Comment: Terrific explanation! Thanks.

Comment: Small note: implicit groupings break with Neo4j 5. Use `WITH` before `RETURN` in that case.